# jQuery: Color fade-rotate

Tags: jquery

I need a function that I can call when somthing is done, for example a fadeOut, fadeIn and so on...

The function I need is a bg-color/font-color rotate with jQuery. I want it to fade betwen two colors for X seconds. Have used google with no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin for that:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color